# OrderClose not working in MQL4 without proper error feedback

Tags: mql4, forex

So I have this EA that should close 2 trades together under certain conditions. Sometimes it closes only 1/2, sometimes it closes both smoothly. I cannot really pinpoint the times it closes only one and detect a pattern so I can spot the logical error.

P.S.: Obviously the trades are from different pairs running from an EA within 1 chart/pair.

The error message is this:
invalid ticket for OrderClose function

But the trade clearly exists, and i make sure I have it within the int as every time I restart the EA, if trade is already open (detected by comment) it has a message like that:
"Buy trade: [ticket number], recognised."
So I know for fact that it is recognised and within the proper int to be used. Any ideas about the error's source?

```
OrderClose(TicketA,LotSize,iClose(NULL,0,0),Slippage,clrGray);
OrderClose(TicketB,LotSize,iClose(SymbolB,0,0),Slippage,clrGray);
```

Will this fix this? I mean... it will be errored out 2/4 close orders... but I don't really care about how beautiful it looks.

```
OrderClose(TicketA,LotSize,Ask,Slippage,clrGray);
OrderClose(TicketB,LotSize,Bid,Slippage,clrGray);
OrderClose(TicketA,LotSize,Ask,Slippage,clrGray);
OrderClose(TicketB,LotSize,Ask,Slippage,clrGray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you didn't override `TicketA` or `TicketB` variable somewhere.

You can use `OrderLots()` function instead of using `LotSize`, especially when this value is changing during EA process. Additionally, by checking the `OrderType()`, you will avoid a mistake at the closing price.

Example:

```
if(yourCloseCondition){
    if(OrderSelect(ticket, SELECT_BY_TICKET)){
        if(OrderType() == OP_BUY){
            if(OrderClose(ticket, OrderLots(), Bid, 0)){
                //Print("success");
            }
        }
        if(OrderType() == OP_SELL){
            if(OrderClose(ticket, OrderLots(), Ask, 0)){
                //Print("success");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also check docs: [OrderClose()](https://docs.mql4.com/trading/orderclose) and [OrderType()](https://docs.mql4.com/trading/ordertype).

**Update:**

For different pairs running within 1 chart use close price from `MarketInfo`

Example:

```
MarketInfo("EURUSD",MODE_BID);
```

Check [MarketInfo()](https://docs.mql4.com/marketinformation/marketinfo).

Comment: So you would suggest I make it:

OrderClose(ticket, OrderLots(), MarketInfo("EURUSD",MODE_BID), 0);

TicketA and TicketB are certainly not overriden. Lotsize is stable, good advise tho.

Comment: Yes, customize the example to your case. If it doesn't help, paste some more code to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Problem solved with some "lightening" and complete re-write. Also used all 6 ways to close order just in case. That results in 4 errors and 2 successful closes. So works.... Thanks!